# Service start fails after Capistrano2 deploy task

Tags: python, init.d

Below is a part of the `/etc/init.d` script that controls a daemon. The full init.script is available at http://pastebin.com/02G5tpgH

```
case "$1" in
start)
        printf "%-50s" "Starting $DAEMON_NAME..."
        cd $DIR
        [ -d $LOGPATH ] || mkdir $LOGPATH
  [ -f $LOGFILE ] || su $DAEMON_USER -c 'touch $LOGFILE'
        PID=`$PYTHON $DAEMON $DAEMON_OPTS > $LOGFILE  2>&1 & echo $!`
        #echo "Saving PID" $PID " to " $PIDFILE
        if [ -z $PID ]; then
            printf "%s\n" "Fail"
        else
            echo $PID > $PIDFILE
            printf "%s\n" "Ok"
        fi
;;
status)
        printf "%-50s" "Checking $DAEMON_NAME..."
        if [ -f $PIDFILE ]; then
            PID=`cat $PIDFILE`
            if [ -z "`ps axf | grep ${PID} | grep -v grep`" ]; then
                printf "%s\n" "Process dead but pidfile exists"
            else
                echo "Running"
            fi
        else
            printf "%s\n" "Service not running"
        fi
;;
stop)
        printf "%-50s" "Stopping $DAEMONNAME"
            PID=`cat $PIDFILE`
            cd $DIR
        if [ -f $PIDFILE ]; then
            kill -HUP $PID
            printf "%s\n" "Ok"
            rm -f $PIDFILE
        else
            printf "%s\n" "pidfile not found"
        fi
;;

restart)
        $0 stop
        $0 start
;;

*)
        echo "Usage: $0 {status|start|stop|restart}"
        exit 1
esac
```

I use capistrano2 to deploy/update this application. So prior to the deploy, i have a task to stop the application/service and then another task to start the service post deploy task. 
The service is never started successfully in this process via the capistrano task. It throws the error.

Process dead but pidfile exists

Manually stopping and starting cannot replicate this issue. So looks like some kind of deamon issue, where the service will not start when called via script

EDITING:

As per the evidences so far, looks like its failing at this part of the script.

```
case "$1" in
start)
        printf "%-50s" "Starting $DAEMON_NAME..."
        cd $DIR
        [ -d $LOGPATH ] || mkdir $LOGPATH
  [ -f $LOGFILE ] || su $DAEMON_USER -c 'touch $LOGFILE'
        PID=`$PYTHON $DAEMON $DAEMON_OPTS > $LOGFILE  2>&1 & echo $!`
        if [ -z $PID ]; then
            printf "%s\n" "Fail"
        else
            echo $PID > $PIDFILE
            printf "%s\n" "Ok"
        fi
;;
```

Comment: Please quote every expansion e.g `"$PIDFILE"`. Don't use CAPITAL letters for normal variable names. Also use  `$(...)`  command substitution instead.   Put  `set -x`  just beneath your `#!/bin/sh`  and see if the var `"$PIDFILE"` is set.

Comment: I stopped counting at five classic horrendous `rc` script mistakes.  I realize from elsewhere that you are on RHEL/CentOS 6 and you have to make do.  But your life will be so much better with version 7 or whatever you eventually upgrade to, when you can stop reinventing the wheel this badly.  Mind you, even [version 6 gives you helpers for avoiding two of the mistakes](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:SysVInitScript#Functions_in_.2Fetc.2Finit.d.2Ffunctions).

Answer (score 0):

This is very odd. If that's your script, then it's not the one that produced the error/reason for the failures, OR Capistrano is sending stdout to something besides the terminal.

The first line of code you presented was: `cat: /var/run/daemon_name.pid: No such file or directory` . The only place you have a cat is in the `status` and `stop` sections. Therefore, you should see the `Checking...` or `Stopping...` output, but you don't. At least, you don't show it.

val0x00ff's suggestion to use set -x at the top of the file is good. If it's too much output, try this:

I would put more messages in your case statement, like this:

```
echo "Got here" 1>&2
```

That will send the message to stderr and you can see what's happening (obviously, the error from cat is going to stderr).

In front of each `` PID= `cat $PIDFILE` `` statement in your code above, do this:

```
{ date; hostname; ls -l /var/run; } 1>&2
```

Make sure everything looks right.

Correcting your variable names and backticks, while they might make for bash code that is more standard or up-to-date, is not the source of your problem here.

Comment: sory i had the issue misinterpreted. The question have been edited.

Comment: You need to go into your script and start spitting out debug code in your start case. I haven't worked with Capistrano, but if you can't see the output from set -x, then you can create printf or echo commands and dump the output to a file in /tmp. For example, when your python daemon runs you don't actually know if it really ran when you echo the PID to the PIDFILE. What's in your LOGFILE? There are so many unknowns that it's hard to debug this. Chuck all your assumptions out the window and answer every question you can think of: "Did my daemon start?" "When is my error message created?" etc..

Answer (score 0):

The cause was not the capistrano, per se. It was due to the process sprawn by capistrano being killed when it exits after the task. We had to modify the init script to fix this issue.'nohup' is used to keep the daemon in the bg even after the cap exist the ssh session. Below is the modified portion of the (start) init script.

```
case "$1" in
start)
    #checking to see if the process is already running, if it is, display a message and exit
    if [ -n "`ps aux |grep  /opt/mount/xyz/current/src/main.py | grep -v grep`" ]; then
      echo "Service is already running, try stopping it first with 'service xyz stop'"
      exit
    fi

    printf "%-50s" "Starting $DAEMON_NAME..."
    cd $DIR
    [ -d $LOGPATH ] || mkdir $LOGPATH
  [ -f $LOGFILE ] || su $DAEMON_USER -c 'touch $LOGFILE'
    nohup $PYTHON $DAEMON $DAEMON_OPTS > $LOGFILE  2>&1 &
    echo $! > $PIDFILE
    sleep 5
;;
```